# Perl - Regex and matching variables

Tags: regex, perl

Good morning guys,

I have the following code:

```
$line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[oO])([_.])[0-9]*";/gene_id "$1$21";/g;
```

And I have problems with $1 and $2. I want the output to be `$1$21`, in other words, `$1` and `$2` and `1`, all together. However, Perl sees `$21` instead of `$2` and `1`. How would I avoid this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use braces around your variable identifier to isolate it from surrounding text, `${2}`

```
$line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*_[oO])([_.])[0-9]*";/gene_id "$1${2}1";/g;
```

Also, since you're keeping all other text the same, you could just use `\K` to only modify what comes after it.  Not to mention utilizing `\w` to reduce your first character class:

```
$line =~ s/gene_id "[\w:\-.]*_[oO][_.]\K[0-9]*";/1";/g;
```

Comment: Hurray for "`\K`eep out"! Concise answer that makes the regex more compact +1 :)